# run bluemix spark job with ibm_db2

Tags: database, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I am trying to run a python spark job that will connect to IBM DB2.

In my driver class, I am importing the following:

```
import ibm_db 
import ibm_db_dbi
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from src.com.ibm.ei.spark.client.elastic.ElasticSearchClient import ElasticSearchClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ibm_db_dbi 
from haversine import haversine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import logging
```

When I comment out the ibm_db imports, my job works fine.

Here is my command:

```
./spark-submit.sh --vcap ./watson-bluemix/streams/udp/bluemix/RegionalLogAnalysis/src/resources/vcap.json --name "LogAggregator" --deploy-mode cluster --master https://169.54.219.20:8443 --py-files ./watson-bluemix/streams/udp/bluemix/RegionalLogAnalysis/dist/RegionalLogAnalysis-0.0.1-py3.5.egg,./zips/elasticsearch-2.3.0.zip,./zips/urllib3-1.14.zip,./zips/haversine-0.4.5.zip ./watson-bluemix/streams/udp/bluemix/RegionalLogAnalysis/src/com/ibm/ei/spark/logs/LogAggregator.py
```

The ibm_db install process installs binary files on my local machine.

I can run the job on my local machine or on any machine where I can manually install ibm_db.

Does anyone have any insights as to successfully run a spark job that connects to DB2 in bluemix?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for, but I have a repo that has 2 notebooks with different kind of DB2/dashDB interfaces https://github.com/data-henrik/CeBIT-Weather
If that is what you want, let me know

Comment: Is there an error message for the import problem ? If yes, can you please add it to the question ? Do you want to access DB2 using Spark or normal Python ? The `ibm_db`and `ibm_db_dbi` packages are for "normal" Python.